# How can i search an exact string using Grep?

Tags: regex, grep

In my Drupal install I was searching for all instances of the variable `$head` and `grep` is returning (overwhelmingly!) both `$head` and `$header`.

What params or flags can I pass into the command so that grep ONLY returns `$head`, and not `$header`?

Comment: Does grep "$head " work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search for exact word using -w option.
Use

```
grep -w string
```

Answer (score 3):

As others mentioned, use `-w` for `grep`. Note also the fact that you need to use single quotes; otherwise, the value `$head` will be expanded by bash into the value of this variable.

```
grep -w '$head' file
#       ^     ^
#     single quotes!
```

You can also use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/\$head\>/p' file
```

The important part here is to use `\>` to state the end of word operator.

```
$ cat a
hello $head is header blabla yea
hello head is $header blabla yea
$ sed -n '/\$head\>/p' a
hello $head is header blabla yea
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fgrep` (or `grep -F`), from the fine manual:

> ```
> -F
> --fixed-strings
> Interpret the pattern as a list of fixed strings 
> (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, 
> any of which is to be matched. (-F is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

Comment: This will still match `$header`.